# Find the $dy/dx$ of $y=y=x\int \limits_2^{x^2}\sin\left(t^3\right){d}t$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for this:
$$y=x\int \limits_2^{x^2}\sin\left(t^3\right){d}t$$
I tried using the chain rule and I am still left with $\int \limits_2^{x^2}\sin\left(t^3\right){d}t$ in my answer as follows:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\int \limits_2^{x^2}\sin\left(t^3\right){d}t+\sin\left(x^6\right)2x^2$$
So, my question is can I eliminate the variable $t$?

Comment: You can never eliminate $t$ because it's a bounded variable (or you can always eliminate it by changing to another variable). What you got finalizes the answer.

Comment: Actually, $t$ is not even a variable of this equation. It's just the variable of integration used in the integral. You could reqrite the Integral as $\frac{y(x)}x$

Comment: What I want is to integrate the definite integral. Thus, There will be only one variable $x$ left.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function of the form
$$c(x)\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\,dt$$
Let $F$ be an anti-derivative or indefinite integral of $f$. Then your function can be rewritten as
$$c(x)\,\left[F(b(x))-F(a(x))\right]$$
where the derivative now can be computed using the product rule, the chain rule and $F'=f$.